# Powershell xml check values

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm iterating through multiple xml files which are stored in $docs. I want to check if certain tags don't have the required values and print there respective ids. But in some xml files all tags may not be present and I want to exclude/skip that tag.
Below is my code, it prints ids with wrong values but it also prints ids if the tag isn't present.

```
$vals= ('sslop','mlop','rxid')
Foreach ($xd in $docs)
{
$id=$xd.'com.xyz.abc.123'.bill.Id
$Cname=$xd.'com.xyz.abc.123'.Class.Name
$Cno=$xd.'com.xyz.abc.123'.Class.ComName
$Cfloor=$xd.'com.xyz.abc.123'.Class.FloorName

if ($Cname -notin $vals -or $Cno -notin $vals -or $Cfloor -notin $vals) {
echo $id
}
```

example xml file 1

```
<com.xyz.abc.123>
<bill>
 <Id>1298</Id>
  <reg>33p</reg>
</bill>
<Class>
  <Name>rxid</Name>
  <Desc>xyz</Desc>
  <ComName>rxid</ComName>
</Class>
</com.xyz.abc.123>
```

Output I get is id `1298` because `<FloorName>` isn't present in the xml file but it shouldn't be the case as `<Name>` and `<ComName>` values are present in `$vals` so I want it to simply skip it.

example xml file 1

```
<com.xyz.abc.123>
<bill>
 <Id>6548</Id>
  <reg>33p</reg>
</bill>
<Class>
  <Name>ferid</Name>
  <Desc>xyz</Desc>
  <ComName>rxid</ComName>
</Class>
</com.xyz.abc.123>
```

Output I get is the id `6548` which is correct as the `<Name>ferid</Name>` is not in $vals.

Comment: can you add a test for "tag aint there"?

Comment: `Id` is in `.bill.Id`, not `.title.Id`. Please provide an accurate example to work with

Comment: @Theo sorry! I have corrected it

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I have improvised rthe question hope it is understandable now.

Comment: So.. If I understand, you want `if ($Cname -in $vals -and $Cno -in $vals -and $Cfloor -in $vals) { echo $id }` ??

Comment: @Mayhan - thank you for the update! [*grin*] it looks like RetiredGeek has provided your Answer ... good!

Answer (score 0):

This will catch the missing tag.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Try {
      $Cfloor=$xd.'com.xyz.abc.123'.Class.FloorName
      $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
      if ($Cname -notin $vals -or 
          $Cno -notin $vals -or 
          $Cfloor -notin $vals) {
      echo $id
    }
}
Catch { 
         #Place processing for missing FloorName here! 
}
```